# Python - how to create multiple scatter plots from pandas dataframe in one figure

Tags: python, plot, linear-regression

Assuming that I have this kind of Dataframe:

```
Tag   X   Y
St2   4   4
st3   7   5
st2   3   2 
st1   2   9
st2   6   4 
st3   2   3 
st1   5   2
```

...............

I would create a sort X Y scatter plot for each Tag number (.groupby ?) , like in the example:

[image]

many many thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, let's say scatter plot

Answer (score 0):

Use a Seaborn FacetGrid.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [1,5,6], [2,5,6], [2,5,9], [3,5,6],  [3,5,1], [4,2,8],[4,1,1], [5,3,9],  [5,6,8]], columns = ['Tag','X','Y'])
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col = 'Tag')
g.map(sns.scatterplot, "X", "Y")
```

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html